# Flutter TabBar how to detect or listen for the being of drag or swipe?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a tab bar with a controller that has a Listener to handle the on tab and user drag/swipe the issue is that I need to know right at the being of the drag so I can start to make the active icon changes with the current version the active icon only changes at the end of the swipe so there is a delay.

Here is my code

In the init state
// For tab selection
tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);

```
// Handles the tab section with on tab and drag
  void _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = tabController.index;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can't detect a swipe or drag in `TabBar` until it's finished. You are better off to `PageView`.

Comment: Yea but its a navigation inside the bottom navigation bar

Comment: Unless you tweak something in the source code or build out your very own `TabBar`, there's no way of doing what you're asking.

Comment: Yea I had that feeling